# rank values based on column entry type

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

i have an sql query that ranks values of a column called 'Total' and returns the result in a computed column called 'Rank'. the query is as follows:

```
String sql ="select s1.Name as 'NAME',s1.Lang as 'LANGUAGE',"
            + "s1.Total as 'TOTAL',COUNT(DISTINCT s2.Total) AS Rank from Type1 s1 JOIN Type1 s2 on(s1.Total<=s2.Total) GROUP BY s1.ID order by s1.Name ASC ";  

    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    table_statistics1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

and it gives the result below:

```
| NAME  | LANGUAGE | TOTAL | RANK| 
------------------------------------------------------
| james|French  |70.0|2nd | 
| jimmy|English |90  |1st |
|  josh|French  |60  |3rd |
|  john|English |40  |4th |
```

i want to write a query that will rank the total column but based on only the language type..so since i have two type of languages,it will rank the total column and return values for only french entries and a seperate rank for only english entries..
so that the output will look like this below:

```
| NAME  | LANGUAGE | TOTAL | RANK| 
------------------------------------------------------ 
| james |French   |70.0    |1st | 
| jimmy |English  |90      |1st |
|josh   |French   |60      |2nd |
|john   |English  |40      |2nd |
```

all suggestions will be very gratefull. thank you.

Comment: tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to rank would use ANSI-standard window functions:

```
select t.Name, t.Lang as LANGUAGE, t.Total,
       dense_rank() over (Partition by t.lang order by t.total) as rnk
from Type t;
```

In SQLite, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct t2.total)
        from t t2
        where t2.lang = t.lang and t2.total <= t.total
       ) as rnk
from Type t;
```

Comment: am using an sqlite3 dbms

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Gordon.. your query for dense_rank() substitute didnt work out but i took an important part which was missing in mine and that was `t2.lang=t.lang`
the final working code is:

```
SELECT S1.*,COUNT(DISTINCT s2.Total) AS Rank from Type s1 JOIN Type s2 on(s2.lang=s1.lang and s1.Total<=s2.Total)GROUP BY s1.ID order by s1.Name ASC
```

thank you very much boss.